# Nuitka Cannot Pack

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Nulkta through pip install commands, but when I run it and try to package it, this is what it give me.

```
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming>nuitka --standalone --recurse-all --output-dir=deploy-nui K0.py
```

And the output

```
__main__.py: can't open file 'K0.py'.
```

K0.py is a simple code that I programmed, contains the following

```
import string
from random import *
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(12, 16)))
print(password)
```

Comment: For `nuitka K0.py` the file `K0.py` must be in the current directory; verify with `dir K0.py`. If it's not in the current directory — change the directory with `cd \path\to\folder` or provide the full path as `nuitka \path\to\K0.py`.

Answer (score 0):

for this case, Nuitka requires admin privileges.